# Odd accuracy error Java

Tags: java

Currently I am attempting to write a change machine in java.  For some reason there is a large loss in accuracy during conversion.

It will first ask for the data values of how much is owed and how much is paid.  Then it will divide out the numbers of quarters and mod out the remainder.  Then it will perform this with dimes, nickles, and then pennies. After this it will then print out how much change is owed.

```
import java.io.*;
import static java.lang.System.*;

import java.util.Scanner;

class change{


     public static void main (String str[]) throws IOException {

            //asker thingy
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter the Cost of the Item:");
            System.out.print("$");
            double costowed = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Please Enter the Amount Payed:");
            System.out.print("$");
            double costpayed = scan.nextDouble();

            //Quarters
            double a1 = Math.round( (costpayed - costowed) * 100);
            int quarters = (int)(a1 / 25);
            int a2 = (int)(a1 % 25);

            //dimes
            int dimes = (int)(a2 / 10);
            int a3 = (int)(a1 % 10);

            //nickles & pennies
            int nickles = (int)(a3 / 5);
            int pennies = (int)(a1 % 5);

            //change owed
            double arc = (double)(a1 / 100);

            //print sequence
            System.out.println("Change owed: " + arc);
            System.out.println("Quarters: " + quarters);
            System.out.println("Dimes: " + dimes);
            System.out.println("Nickles: " + nickles);
            System.out.println("Pennies: " + pennies);
     }

}
```

Comment: Firstly - what exactly is the problem?  Secondly I recommend that you use BigDecimal for money.

Comment: just a side note but you don't need to include loonies or toonies into this? What about bills for change? Or do you just give out a trillion quarters if the discrepency between amount paid and item price is high?

Comment: @miss.serena -- It's such a two-bit operation that there's never more than a quarter change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
int a3 = (int)(a1 % 10);
```

should be:

```
int a3 = (int)(a2 % 10);
```

And likewise `int pennies = (int)(a1 % 5);` should be `int pennies = (int)(a3 % 5);`.